# Azure Function-App is not logging to console or AppInsights

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure Function with AzureFunctionVersion v3 and for some time now I don't see any logs in Application Insights or in the Rider Console that are not logged in the FunctionTrigger itself.

```cs
[FunctionName("test")]
public IActionResult Test([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "delete", Route = BasePath + "/{roomId}")] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
{
   log.LogInformation("Log is shown");

   myservice.DoIt();
}
```

```cs
namespace MyApp.Test.Service {
   public MyService(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   {       
     _log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(GetType().Namespace);
   }

   public void DoIt() {
      _log.LogInformation("Log is not shown");
   }
}
```

My host.json looks like:

```json
"logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": false
            }
        },
        "logLevel": {
            "MyApp.*": "Information"
        }
    }
```

Comment: One thing i know is that wildcard symbols are not supported. So `MyApp.*` won't work. Try "MyApp" instead, it will apply the log level to all subcategories

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try to change the `logLevel` in one of the following ways:

1. `"logLevel": {"MyApp": "Information"}`
2. `"logLevel": { "Default": "Information" }`